# psycopg2 "IndexError: tuple index out of range" Error when using '%' like operator with arguments tuple

Tags: python, psycopg2

This works fine:

```
 cc.execute("select * from books where name like '%oo%'")
```

But if second argument passed:

```
cursor.execute("select * from books where name like '%oo%' OFFSET % LIMIT %", (0,1))
```

Psycopg errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

How to avoid this error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, you should use `%%` to insert `%` literal, otherwise, library will try to use all `%` as placeholders. Second, it's better to specify `%s`, where you want to insert values.

So, your code should look like:

```
cursor.execute("select * from books where name like '%%oo%%' OFFSET %s LIMIT %s", (0,1))
```

Comment: Beware that in python 3 you'll want to add another comma in your tuple: `cursor.execute("select * from books where name like '%%oo%%' OFFSET %s LIMIT %s", (0,1,))`, otherwise you get `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`.